# Upload multiple file thru php

Tags: php, upload

So heres my php upload script. I can insert those filenames in database but the problem is  I cant move those images to the target destination.

```
<?php

    require_once('./ssl/ecommerce/config/connect.php');

    $dir = "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/excelsispharma/assets/images/news_events/";
    $file = $_POST['file'];
    $evtName = $_POST['evtName'];


    $sql = "INSERT INTO excelsis_news_events.event(event_name)".
            " VALUES('$evtName') ";
    $ex = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $last = $mysqli->insert_id;
    echo $last;

    foreach ($file as $key ) {

        $sql = " INSERT INTO excelsis_news_events.images(event_id,filename) ".
                " VALUES('$last','$key') ";
        $run = $mysqli->query($sql);

        move_uploaded_file($file,$dir);

    }




?>
```

Comment: the files should be in $_FILES array not post

Comment: heres my fiddle sir http://jsfiddle.net/roowako/Q768j/ can you check it out and give me idea on how i can move uploaded files thru that code(mycode) thanks